# CDF of function of two random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

I'm a little confused about how to approach the below question:

Q: Let $\,W=Y-X$ and determine the CDF of $W$.

[image]

I've read the solution, [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/unit-ii/lecture-9/MIT6_041SCF13_assn05_sol.pdf), but this was not very clear and I was wanting an approach from calculus if possible (unless this is too messy).

I understand that $w=-1$ is the point that splits the region but am not sure how to set the integrals up - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is to find the cdf of $W$ where $W=Y-X$ in order to do that we know that the joint density of $W$ is given by

$$ F_{W}(w) = \iint_{D} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy \tag{1}$$

Where the joint density is split into two uniform densities

$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} &  0 \leq x \leq 1 , 0\leq  y\leq 1  \\ \\ \frac{3}{2}  &  1 \leq x \leq 2 , 0 \leq y \leq 1 \end{cases} \end{align} \tag{2}$$

It notes the following

$$ P(W \leq w) = P(Y-X \leq w ) =P(Y \leq X +w) \tag{3}$$

Which gives us this picture

[image]

While you could use calculus and I actually spent a while preparing an answer with it. There is no point. They are made of triangles it notes that in the answer.

> The probabilities of interest can be calculated by taking advantage of
>   the uniform PDF over the two triangles.

Now instead if you actually look at the picture. I am pasting it

[image]

The area of a triangle is $A = \frac{1}{2}b \cdot h $
$$ I_{1} = f_{X,Y}(x,y) \frac{1}{2} \frac{(2+w)}{2} (2+w) \tag{4} $$

$$ I_{1} = \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{(2+w)}{2} (2+w) \tag{5} $$
$$ I_{1} = \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{(2+w)^{2}}{2} \tag{6} $$

The other region is $1+w$  which would be only $\frac{1}{2}$ for the joint density. It is the triangular region in the middle.
[image]

$$ I_{2} = f_{X,Y}(x,y) \frac{1}{2} (1+w)(1+w) \tag{7} $$
$$ I_{2} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} (1+w)^{2} \tag{8} $$

Look at the top now. See the triangle. The base is $-w$ and the height is $\frac{-w}{2}$

$$ I_{3} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{-w}{2} \cdot -w = \frac{w^{2}}{4}\tag{9} $$

We want the region for $w \in (-1,0)$ so now the area of the whole right side is

$$ I_{4} = \frac{1}{2} 1 \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2} \tag{10}$$

If we subtract off the triangle before we get this area

[image]

So we let

$$ I_{5} = f_{X,Y}(x,y)(I_{4} -I_{3}) \tag{11} $$
$$ I_{5} = \frac{3}{2}(\frac{1}{2} -\frac{w^{2}}{4}) \tag{12} $$

Note this a cumulative density. We just added the region for $I_{1}$ now let's add $I_{2}$ call it $I_{6}$ and make our $F_{W}(w)$

$$ I_{6} = I_{2} + I_{5} \tag{13}$$

$$ I_{6} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} (1+w)^{2} +   \frac{3}{2}(\frac{1}{2} -\frac{w^{2}}{4}) \tag{14}$$

$$ f_{W}(w) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} 0 &  \textrm{ if }  w < -2  \\ \\ \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{(2+w)^{2}}{2}  &  \textrm{ if } -2 \leq w \leq -1 \\ \\  \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} (1+w)^{2} +   \frac{3}{2}(\frac{1}{2} -\frac{w^{2}}{4}) & \textrm{ if } -1 < w \leq 0 \\ \\ 1 & \textrm{ if } w > 0  \end{cases} \end{align} \tag{15}$$

fixing this like they did

$$ f_{W}(w) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} 0 &  \textrm{ if }  w < -2  \\ \\ \frac{3}{8} (2+w)^{2}  &  \textrm{ if } -2 \leq w \leq -1 \\ \\  \frac{1}{8}\big(-w^{2} +4w +8 \big) & \textrm{ if } -1 < w \leq 0 \\ \\ 1 & \textrm{ if } w > 0  \end{cases} \end{align} \tag{16}$$